# Parse server deployed on Amazon EC2 Android notifications with FCM

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have two columns on my Parse Server called `acceptedBy`  and `username` and want to send notification when state of the `acceptedBy` column changes.

`acceptedBy` and `username` columns always consist of two different users. `acceptedBy` always changes to current user and at that point I would like to send notification to user in `username` column.

I need to do this for Android app using FCM. What would be the steps to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it by using `notify.php` and transferring it to website which can be run from application like `http://yourdomain.com/notify.php?Action=M&t=message title here&m=body here&r=your app token here`.

notify.php:

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```